# in line "let oggi =..." the program tell me "expected expression" how can i fix it?

Tags: ios, xcode

in line "let oggi =..." the program tell me "expected expression" how can i fix it?

```
func daysToXmas () -> Int{
            let oggi = Calendar.current.dateComponents(Set<Calendar.Component>, from: Date, .month, .year, from:self);)

            var nataleComponents = DateComponents()
            nataleComponents.year = 2015
            nataleComponents.month = 12
            nataleComponents.day = 25
            let natale = Calendar.current.date(from: nataleComponents)!


            let components: NSCalendar.Unit = .NSDayCalendarUnit
            let diff = Calendar.currentCalendar().components(components, fromDate: oggi!, toDate: natale, options: nil)
            return diff.day

         }

    }
```

Comment: Please format your code properly

Comment: how can i do? sorry but i'm new on the site

Comment: `func daysToXmas () -> I...` should be formatted as code, not as text

Comment: Should the semicolon be outside the second parenthesis?

Comment: this is the code

Comment: thanks easton bornemeier

Comment: i add a semicolon at the end of second parenthesis but the error doesn't disappear, tells me Expected Expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Che guazzabuglio* ;-) (What a jumble)

You probably mean

```
let oggi = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .year], from: Date())
```

To get the remaining days until next Xmas there is a smarter way. It gets the date of next Xmas (regardless of the year) and calculates the days between.

```
func daysToXmas() -> Int {
    let nataleComponents = DateComponents(month:12, day:25)
    let prossimoNatale = Calendar.current.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: nataleComponents, matchingPolicy: .strict)!
    return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: Date(), to: prossimoNatale).day!
}
```

Comment: ok thanks, but now in the line let diff =... the program tells me "type 'calendar' has no member 'currentCalendar'"

Comment: You are mixing up Swift 2  and 3 syntax. I will update the answer with a smart solution.